# jasper variable expression

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I want to declare a variable in a Jasper, of type Integer, that is incremented at the footer of one of my report groups, and reset to 0 at the footer of another report group. How can I specify this in the expression for the variable?

Answer (score 0):

In the Report Inspector, right-click "Variables" to create a new variable. Name it, set the variable class to java.lang.Integer. Set the calculation type (maybe you're summing over a group?), set the rest type to group, set the rest group to the name of your group, and set the initial value expression to 0 to reset it when a new group begins.